# Delete Rows from Object Type Column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My objective is to delete all the rows that have the word `Drop` in the column `Drop`.

The column has the next properties:

`df.dtypes['Drop']`: `dtype('O')`

`type(df['Drop'])`: `pandas.core.series.Series`

I have tried:

```
indexNames = df[df['Drop'] == 'Drop'].index
df.drop(indexNames, inplace=True)

df.drop(df['Drop'] == 'Drop', axis=0)

df['Drop_1'] = df.where((df['Drop'] == 'Drop'), 1, 0)
df.drop(df['Drop_1'] == 1, axis=0)
df.drop(df['Drop_1'])
```

Comment: Will you please add a small sample of your dataframe?

Comment: ```df.loc[~df.Drop.str.contains('Drop')]``` will remove the rows that contain the word 'Drop' in the Drop column. Note that you can add to ```str.contains('...',case=False)``` and make it case insensitive. More info about ```str.contains``` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove rows from the dataframe where `Drop` is is in the `Drop` column for those rows:

```
df = df[~df['Drop'].astype(str).str.contains('Drop')]
```